# how to use geocoder class to retrieve latitude and longitude through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

> the json array which contains the list of addresses

```html
[
{
"id": 0,
"title": "Coop.Sociale Prassi e Ricerca Onlus", 
"latitude": 0,
"longitude": 0,
"address": "Viale Eleonora D'Arborea 12, Roma, IT"
},
{
"id": 0,
"title": "San Lorenzo", 
"latitude": 0,
"longitude": 0,
"address": "Viale della Primavera 330, Roma, IT"
},
{
"id": 0,
"title": "Giardinetti", 
"latitude": 0,
"longitude": 0,
"address": "Via Molfetta 45, Roma, IT"
},
{
"id": 0,
"title": "Montesacro", 
"latitude": 0,
"longitude": 0,
"address": "Viale Parioli, Roma, IT"
},
{
"id": 0,
"title": "Casa", 
"latitude": 0,
"longitude": 0,
"address": "Piazza Vescovio, Roma, IT"
}
]
```

> this is the javascript file which asynchronously loads the json array in which there is a list of addresses, latitudes and longitudes that are retrieved through an ajax request. codeAddress is a function which retrieves the address and coverts it to latitude and longitude

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var arr = [];
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.90832, 12.52407);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD3Xz7-z7U_XzZiaOlx9khhtFSld8vd0k4' +
      '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "json/array.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
function myFunction(response) {
    arr = JSON.parse(response);
function codeAddress(x) {
  var address = arr[x].address;
  console.log(arr[x].address);
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
 arr[x].latitude = results[0].geometry.location.A;
 console.log(arr[x].latitude);
 arr[x].longitude = results[0].geometry.location.F;
 console.log(arr[x].longitude);
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
}
function myLoop() {
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   codeAddress(i);
   console.log(arr[i].address);
}  
}

> the css code which makes the map visible
```

```css
 html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }

> the html part contains a click event which fires whenever the geocode button is clicked. This event retrieves the function myLoop in the js file
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <script src="js/geocode_ajax.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Roma, IT">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="myLoop()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> the error returned is: codeAddress is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of it's [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), your `codeAddress` javascript function is not visible for outer caller `myLoop`, as **it is enclosed within `myFunction`**, therefore you get the `codeAddress is not defined`.

Try to rewrite your code similar to this (I have not tested, so it might not work right away, but you get the idea):

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var arr = [];
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.90832, 12.52407);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD3Xz7-z7U_XzZiaOlx9khhtFSld8vd0k4' +
      '&signed_in=true&callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "json/array.json";
var arr;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        arr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();


function codeAddress(x) {
  var address = arr[x].address;
  console.log(arr[x].address);
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    arr[x].latitude = results[0].geometry.location.A;
    console.log(arr[x].latitude);
    arr[x].longitude = results[0].geometry.location.F;
    console.log(arr[x].longitude);
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function myLoop() {
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   codeAddress(i);
   console.log(arr[i].address);
}  
}
```

Comment: that works and the problem was to get rid of muFunction